# Symfony2 flash messages from Entity Repository

Tags: symfony, entity

Is there a way to write flash messages from entity repository. I have a Tag and Category entity. 
I am adding tags via Category form, where i added a custom input field that receives tags separated with ", ". Every time i submit a form i check if the tags in the input already exist, if not i add them to the database and then i add them to the Category entity.

Here is my tag repository where im trying to write the flashmessage:

```
namespace Kpr\CentarZdravljaBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Kpr\CentarZdravljaBundle\Entity\Tags;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class TagsRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findByTagInput($arg)
    {
        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        $args = explode(", ", $arg);

        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $tagArray = array();
        $addaedTags = "";
        foreach($args as $name){
            $tag = $this->findByName($name);
            if(!$tag){
                $addaedTags .= $name.", ";
                $newTag = new Tags();
                $newTag->setName($name);
                $newTag->setApproved(1);
                $em->persist($newTag);
                $tagArray[] = $newTag;
            }
        }
        if($addaedTags!="") $request->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('info', substr($addaedTags,0,strlen($addaedTags)-2));
        $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

        $qb->add('select', 'tag')
           ->add('from', 'KprCentarZdravljaBundle:Tags tag')
           ->add('where', $qb->expr()->in('tag.name', $args));
        // $qb instanceof QueryBuilder
        $query = $qb->getQuery();
        // Set additional Query options
        $query->useResultCache('my_cache_id');
        $results = $query->getResult();
        /*
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE $whereS";
        $stmt = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
        $results = $stmt->execute();
        */

        $totalResults = array_merge($tagArray, $results);
        $tags = new ArrayCollection($totalResults);
        return $tags;
    }

    public function findByName($name)
    {
        $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

        $qb->add('select', 'tag')
           ->add('from', 'KprCentarZdravljaBundle:Tags tag')
           ->add('where', 'tag.name = :namearg')
           ->setParameter('namearg', $name);
        // $qb instanceof QueryBuilder
        $query = $qb->getQuery();
        $result = $query->getResult();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

The error i get:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getFlashBag() 
on a non-object in /home/kprhr/public_html/CZ_Symfony/src/Kpr/CentarZdravljaBundle/Entity/TagsRepository.php line 31
```

Comment: Entity repositories are not meant to handle this kind of logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should handle the request from the EntityManager ; their purposes are different. The EntityManager manages the communication between the DB and your application, it's not its purpose to handle session management, neither is it to add flashes messages.

This job should go to a dedicated service, which will handle that.

Now, your error comes from the way you get your request. You are actually creating a brand new object, which is not properly instanciated, by using the static method createFromGlobals. Instead, you should handle the flash messages in your controller.

This would translate as something like that:

```
//Controller

public function mypageAction()
{
    // Your logic
    if (count($args) > 0) {
        $this->getRequest()->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('info', implode(',', $args));
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: i just remembered is there a way to store names of the new tag objects i created in a session?

Comment: sure, you should be able to do that with $this->getRequest()->get('session')->set('key', $args) or something like that (syntax needs to be checked)

Comment: hmmm... do you have a better idea how i can get the $addaedTags variable from the repository to the controler?

Comment: Actually, everything above your QueryBuilder creation should be in the controller, the rest can stay in the EntityRepository. Then you call the method with an array of Tag objects as parameters. This way, you'll have your $addeableTags variable in your controller.

Comment: Sadly that wouldnt work cuz i have a data transformer that transforms the input for tags into tag objects. The transformer calls the findByTagInput($arg) function of the repository and the function gives him back objects which it then sends to the controller. So if there is a tag in the inputbox that does not exists i have to via the findByTagInput($arg) function create it and pass the created object to the transformer that passes it to the controller.

Comment: Well in that case, you're probably calling findByTagInput from your controller. Hence you can perform the logic of $addaedTags inside as well (check the PHP implode function to do that).